# std::string as out parameter or return value

Tags: c++, stdstring

Which is the correct way to get an std::string value from a function. The assumption here is that I am writing the function and the caller.

```
std::string foo()
{
     std::string str = "ABC";
     return str;
}
```

OR

```
void foo(std::string &str)
{
    str = "ABC";
}
```

I understand that in the first method compiler optimizations will come into the picture and return by value will not be a big overhead so this method should be just fine.

The second method guarantees that there is no copy involved so it's going to be always efficient.

Which method would be your choice?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. `std::string foo()` is useful because the value can be obtained without creating varaibles lile `std::cout << foo();` from this form.

Comment: My advice, avoid using out parameters.  It forces you to split the initialization of the variable to store the return value and the function call, which is an invitation for bugs.

Comment: out paramaters don't chain. Also consider how the calling code looks like `foo(some_string)` vs `some_string = foo();` with wich one you know for sure that `some_string` is returned? The question is purely opinion -based btw

Comment: Even the first method guarantees no copying.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov Not really.  At best NRVO will apply (which is not guaranteed), at medium a move will happen, otherwise it falls back to just a copy.  With SSO, more than likely a copy will happen since arrays can't be moved.

Comment: btw there is a third option that is really common in operator overloading and that is to combine both, though then it is a reference that is returned : `std::string& foo(std::string&);` they all have their place, but unless there is a reason to deviate from the default I agree that `std::string foo()` should be the default

Comment: actually the c++ core guidelines cover this here: https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-out (it still is just a guideline, subject to opinions and preference)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As said in the comments, using a return by value seems to be preferred nowadays. I find my code to be more readable that way, in that you can see that there is actually a change.

With the out parameter foo(str) it's not obvious that str is being changed.

I believe all mainstream compilers are clever enough to optimize away any unnecessary copying.

So, in essence, it's more about readability and clarity than anything else.

Comment: dont you think a couple of comments is too little statistics to conclude that it is "preferred nowadays" ?

Comment: Do you have any reputable references (such as published best practices) to back this assertion? As it stands this answer is an opinion and not a definitive answer.